# How do I uninstall a Kernel Extension in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, kernel-extensions

I've recently reformatted my MBP to Yosemite and have run into an issue with my Logitech mouse. After doing some research I discovered that this is a longstanding issue. In the process of trying to fix this, I've installed (and tried to uninstall) several different driver kernel extensions.

I've removed these drivers from system preferences (by right clicking) but I've noticed that there are still the .kext files in /Library/Extensions folder.

Is it same to simply delete the related files and restart my computer to remove the extensions, or do I need to use some kind of tool to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't go playing with kexts. They don't like being dragged around. You'll end up with a kernel panic and have to pick it apart in single user mode - let's leave that kind of thing to the hackintosh kiddies.

Logitech Control Center (LCC) comes with an uninstaller in /Applications/Utilities which would be a far better bet.